# How to get the 6 extra specializations on Halo 4 with an offline profile?

Tags: halo-4

I have reached SR70 with my offline profile on Halo 4. As far as I can tell, the only way to get a higher rank/specialization is by going on Xbox Live, which will reset my XP (not an option). How can I get these specializations (Pathfinder, Stalker, Pioneer, etc.) on my offline profile? I don't mind using a hack.